# Is it possible to pass the row values to a DataGrid subcomponent?

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I have a DataGrid table with `checkboxSelection` enabled. I'm trying to disable the ability to select a row through the checkBox when the row has a certain value in a given column.

Example, if my rows where like this:

```
const rows = [
  { id: 1, lastName: 'Snow', firstName: 'Jon', age: 35 },
  { id: 2, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Cersei', age: 42 },
  { id: 3, lastName: 'Lannister', firstName: 'Jaime', age: 45 },
  { id: 4, lastName: 'Stark', firstName: 'Arya', age: 16 },
  { id: 5, lastName: 'Targaryen', firstName: 'Daenerys', age: null },
  { id: 6, lastName: 'Melisandre', firstName: null, age: 150 },
  { id: 7, lastName: 'Clifford', firstName: 'Ferrara', age: 44 },
  { id: 8, lastName: 'Frances', firstName: 'Rossini', age: 36 },
  { id: 9, lastName: 'Roxie', firstName: 'Harvey', age: 65 },
];
```

I'd like the selection to be disabled if `age` is null or > 100.

I've tried to add an additional prop with `componentsProps` so that it could be later passed to a custom `BaseCheckbox` component, but I get the impression that `params.row` isn't available here.

Any pointers? Or ideas of where I could look around?

I'm using v5.14.0 of MUI.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do? https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-selection/#disable-selection-on-certain-rows

Comment: huh, I must be blind! That section totally escaped me when I was reading that doc. Thank you!